# how can I remove this one in beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get only the text **save** in the html below using bs and discard the text **del**. How can I do that?

```
<div>
<span class="chk_box">
  <input id="subj5" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="5"/>
  <label for="subj5">
   SAVE1
  </label>
 </span>
 <span class="chk_box">
  <input id="subj6" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="6"/>
  <label for="subj6">
   SAVE2
  </label>
 </span>
 <span class="chk_box">
  <input disabled="" id="subj7" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="7"/>
  <label for="" subj7""="">
  DEL1
  </label>
 </span>
 <span class="chk_box">
  <input disabled="" id="subj8" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="8"/>
  <label for="subj78">
   DEL2
  </label>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the discriminating feature is that the items you want to extract are missing `disabled=''` in `input`. So you could filter on that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div>
<span class="chk_box">
  <input id="subj5" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="5"/>
  <label for="subj5">
   SAVE1
  </label>
 </span>
 <span class="chk_box">
  <input id="subj6" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="6"/>
  <label for="subj6">
   SAVE2
  </label>
 </span>
 <span class="chk_box">
  <input disabled="" id="subj7" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="7"/>
  <label for="" subj7""="">
  DEL1
  </label>
 </span>
 <span class="chk_box">
  <input disabled="" id="subj8" name="subj" onclick="subjSel();" type="checkbox" value="8"/>
  <label for="subj78">
   DEL2
  </label>
 </span>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
results = [i.find_next_sibling().get_text().strip() for i in soup.find_all('input', {'disabled':None})]
```

Output:

```
['SAVE1', 'SAVE2']
```